# How to clear unwanted records in Kinvey Database

Tags: java, android, database, kinvey

I am having an Android app and I am planning to use Kinvey Database to store some data.

One of the record in the entry would be having the last used time period.

The last used time period will be set by my app when ever the app is opened.

What basically I am trying to achieve is to run a code at the end of each month and clear all the record whos value of the last used period is more than 10 days.

Can any one please tell me whether it is possible to do this?

The reason for doing this is to use the least Server storage space as they provide only 1 GB/Monthly in the free plan.

Answer (score 2):

What I understand from this...

*What basically I am trying to achieve is to run a code at the end of each month and clear all the record whos value of the last used period is more than 10 days.
Can any one please tell me whether it is possible to do this?*

... is that you would like to have scheduled code, which will be executed once a month. Please take a further look at the Scheduled Code feature of Kinvey.

https://devcenter.kinvey.com/html5/tutorials/scheduled-code-getting-started

Edit: more information on the topic...

Kinvey Scheduled code allows you to execute one of your [custom endpoints](https://devcenter.kinvey.com/html5/guides/business-logic#custom-endpoints) on a specific date in the future. It is commonly used to

- Aggregate, archive, and cleanup data.
- Pull data from a third-party API into Kinvey.
- Send out a batch of e-mails or push notifications.

I would not bother describing step-by-step initializing of Scheduled Code, since those steps may change in the future. Please follow the steps from the link above, those should be fine to get you further.